# django 1.11.3 css background image not showing

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to have my background image show using css in django 1.11.3 and have received some 404 errors in the terminal when running the server that the picture can't load. My css file does load and can change the contents in my `home.html` file.

home.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row img-bg">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <a href='#'>My Button</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.img-bg{
  background: url('../img/logo.png'); // 404 error
  background: url('../assets/img/logo.png'); // 404 error
  background: url("{% static 'img/logo.png' %}"); // 404 error
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

folder structure

```
website_src
  --assets
    --css
      --style.css
    --img
       --logo.png
```

Comment: what is the source of the img? Right click and Copy Image Location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change in your **css** file because you are serving all your files in assets via `/static/`

```
.img-bg{
  background: url('/static/img/logo.png');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Django 3.0.5

I've learned to do the following...

```
# settings.py
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your+project/static')
]
```

So you can just add background images without single quotes or using /static/img/image.jpg.

- Make sure you have run `python manage.py collectstatic` after changes
  or inserting CSS files.
- There are two static folders that need to have had the same change,
  one in the root and one in the main folder named after your project.
- Make sure you're not using `background: url(../img/image.jpg)
  no-repeat top center fixed/cover;` instead, use `background:
  url(../img/showcase.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;`. Which I
  believe is a browser CSS compatibility issue, more specific on chrome.
- You can always use inline styling and point to the source with
  /static?`<section id="showcase" style="background: url('/static/img/showcase.jpg') no-repeat top center fixed;">`.

Comment: Just want to add that you might want to clear your browser cache

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

To:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

and then `python manage.py collectstatic`, see if this helps.